# Slow socket's recv on Windows for lots of small messages

Tags: java, windows, sockets, python-2.7

I'm developing small server in Python using the sockets library (SOCK_STREAM). The server is supposed to receive a lot of small messages (25-40bytes), process them and forward as fast as possible.

On Linux and OSX it works perfectly, socket's recv function returns data as soon as it arrives. Unfortunately on Windows (8 Pro) it seems to accumulate data before returning returning it from recv function.

I've tried to limit maximum amount of data read using the recv function, but that didn't help much. Looks like data is accumulated internally.

Is there any specific Socket Option I had to set in server (Python) or in client (Java's Socket)?

**EDIT**

One of my colleagues suggested to round up each message to 1KB by filling it with dummy data.
This may help to avoid internal buffers @PeterLawrey pointed to.

I didn't have a chance to try it. Do you think it may help and it's valid and widely adopted technique?

Comment: Do you use TCP? You're setting SO_NODELAY right? Otherwise the sender will buffer data.

Comment: if he's getting the data on other platforms, it shouldn't be a problem.. assuming he's using the same sender regardless of where the server is running.

Comment: @Joni I do not set any specific option on client, so it defaults to standard Java's options on Android I suppose. On the server I only set SO_REUSEADDR.

Comment: @xaxxon The code for server and client is the same on all platforms.

Comment: Have you confirmed with e.g. wireshark or tcpdump that the data is getting sent?

Comment: @Joni I confirm that data is received. It then used to do some visual stuff. What I experience visually is jittering. It runs smoothly on Linux and OSX.

Comment: You can turn off nagle but the OS and the network adapter can do it's own coalescing.  I would suggest the network adapter rather than the OS.

Answer (score -1):

The way to manipulate the amount of kernel memory held for a socket in a Java program is to set SO_RCVBUF (in a C/C++ program you'd use `setsockopt` to do this).

I'd rather not reproduced large amounts of code here but rather give you some pointers to look at.

[Documentation of SocketOptions](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html) 
[Documentation of SO_RCVBUF](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_RCVBUF)

You can use those to cut down the amount that the kernel will buffer before it returns stuff to you.

That said, I can't see any reason why if your application has a SOCK_STREAM, it doesn't immediately return any data available. I think something else is likely the issue.

Comment: Server's code is as simple as while look with select/recv inside. Client's code uses `out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);` to create output stream. It flushes out after each "message" is written.